# rvest: trying to build a csv/table from a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to build a table/data frame/csv file that looks like:

```
( [City1, State1], OverallScore1, QualityOfLife1, Value1 )
( [City2, State2], OverallScore2, QualityOfLife2, Value2 )
...
( [CityN, StateN], OverallScoreN, QualityOfLifeN, ValueN )
```

I am able to grab only one of any of the three values (`OverallScore`, `QualityOfLife` and `Value`) for a single `(City, State)` with the code:

```
library(rvest)
live_movie <- read_html("https://realestate.usnews.com/places/rankings/best-places-to-live")
live %>%
  html_node('#main-well') %>%
  html_node('.text-large-for-small-only') %>%
  html_text()
```

Is there a way to grab ALL of the aforementioned fields in one go?

Comment: @hrbrmstr which part would the above operation be in violation of?

Comment: @hrbrmstr This data is for my personal use. I am interested in compiling information on places that I should consider moving to.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code according to the guidelines mentioned in the comments.

```
library(rvest)
url<- "https://realestate.usnews.com/places/rankings/best-places-to-live"
page<-read_html(url)

overall_score<-html_nodes(page,css=".text-tightest:nth-child(1) .text-coal") %>% html_text()
overall_score<-as.numeric(gsub(" Overall Score","",overall_score))

life_quality<-html_nodes(page, css=".text-tightest:nth-child(2) .text-coal") %>% html_text()
life_quality<-as.numeric(gsub("[\r\n QualityofLife]", "", life_quality))

value<-html_nodes(page, css=".border-left-for-medium-up+ .text-tightest .text-coal") %>% html_text()
value<-as.numeric(gsub("[\r\n Value]", "", value))

heading<-html_nodes(page, css=".heading-large a") %>% html_text()
city<-sapply(heading,function(x){strsplit(x,split=", ")[[1]][1]})
state<-sapply(heading,function(x){strsplit(x,split=", ")[[1]][2]})


real_estate<-data.frame(city,state,overall_score,life_quality,value, row.names = NULL)
```